# Change blur of UIVisualEffectView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview

How do I change the blur of an existing VisualEffectView programmatically from, for example .light to .dark?

I have tried like this

Outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var visualEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
```

Trying to change blur:

```
let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
visualEffect.effect = darkBlur
```

Comment: don't you have an answer inside your question already?

Comment: No, that is just what i have tried. The code does not work..

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Does it run fine but doesn't change the blur? Help us help you.

Comment: When using inside a function that I use in the tapButton action it runs fine, but does not change the blur. When I put it directly inside the tapButton action it crashes and gets : "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Comment: Since you did include the full "function" you just referred to in your question, this is just a guess - but it sounds like either (a) `visualEffect` is nil - the outlet isn't properly connected - or (b) something with variable scope.

Comment: My outlet wasn't properly connected, had no idea... thanks!